# Write type constraint for polymorphic variants with generic type parameters

Tags: ocaml, reason

Background: I was trying to create something as described in the paper, [Data Type à la Carte](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~W.Swierstra/Publications/DataTypesALaCarte.pdf) - but trying to see if OCaml's polymorphic variants could lead to a clean ReasonML implementation.

My code here is in ReasonML syntax, but the question is equally applicable to OCaml.

I start by defining two modules for a `Val` and a `Add`, both implementing an `fmap` - making them a haskel-style functor.

```reason
module type Functor = {
  type t('a);
  let fmap: ('a => 'b, t('a)) => t('b);
};

module Val = {
  type t('e) = [ | `Val(int)];
  let fmap = _ =>
    fun
    | `Val(x) => `Val(x);
};

module Add = {
  type t('e) = [ | `Add('e, 'e) ];

  let fmap = f =>
    fun
    | `Add(x, y) => `Add((f(x), f(y)))
};
```

I can fairly easily create an `Algebra` data type that combines these two modules into one, with a really simple `fmap` implementation.

```reason
module Algebra = {
  type t('t) = [ Val.t('t) | Add.t('t)];

  let fmap = (f, x) =>
    switch (x) {
    | #Val.t as v => Val.fmap(f, v)
    | #Add.t as o => Add.fmap(f, o)
    };
};
```

This compiles and works in a larger context where I can evaluate an expression consisting of both `Val` and `Add` values.

However, as a programmer who would like to avoid writing boiler-plate code, my next step would be to create a functor (OCaml functor) that can generate such a module from any two compatible modules.

My first attempt is this:

```reason
module JoinAlgebra = (A1: Functor, A2: Functor) => {
  type t('t) = [ A1.t('t) | A2.t('t)];

  let fmap = (f, x) =>
    switch (x) {
    | #A1.t as v => Val.fmap(f, v)
    | #A2.t as o => Add.fmap(f, o)
    };
};
```

But this doesn't work. As the `A1.t` and `A2.t` can be anything, I cannot combine them as a polymorphic variant.

> Error: The type A1.t('t) is not a polymorphic variant type

I tried adding a type constraint to the `Functor` module  type:

```reason
module type Functor = {
  type t('a) = 'a constraint [> ] = 'a;
  let fmap: ('a => 'b, t('a)) => t('b);
};

module JoinAlgebra = (A1: Functor, A2: Functor) => {
  type t('t) = [ A1.t('t) | A2.t('t)]; // This line fails
}
```

Now I get the compiler error

> Error: The type A1.t([>  ]) is not a polymorphic variant type

Is there any way I can create a module-functor that automatically based on the two modules?

**A note about OCaml versions**: I am using bucklescript v. 5 here, which uses the OCaml 4.02 compiler. But solutions that require 4.06 are also welcome (support should be coming to Bucklescript)

Answer (score 2):

Your `Functor` signature defines an abstract type `'a t`. As you correctly point out, "as the A1.t and A2.t can be anything, I cannot combine them as a polymorphic variant." To solve the problem that `'a t` in `Functor` is abstract, you try to make it a polymorphic variant by doing:

```ml
module Functor = struct
  type 'a t = 'a constraint 'a = [< ]
end
```

However, the `'a` type variable no longer stands for the wrapped value, but rather the polymorphic variant constraint. This is certainly not what you want. You get the error `Error: The type A1.t([> ]) is not a polymorphic variant type` because you can only substitute "exact variant types" into polymorphic variants:

> The first case is an exact variant type: all possible tags are known, with their associated types, and they can all be present. Its structure is fully known.
>
> ...
>
> In all three cases, tags may be either specified directly in the `tag-name  [of typexpr] form, or indirectly through a type expression, which must expand to an exact variant type, whose tag specifications are inserted in its place.

(https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/types.html#polymorphic-variant-type)

You don't need polymorphic variants for your `JoinAlgebra`. Just do:

```ml
module JoinAlgebra (A1 : Functor) (A2 : Functor) = struct
  type 't t = Left of 't A1.t | Right of 't A2.t

  let fmap f x =
    match x with
    | Left v -> Left (A1.fmap f v)
    | Right o -> Right (A2.fmap f o)
end
```

The benefit is that the `'a t` in `Functor` remains abstract and the code works for `Functor` modules that do not define polymorphic variants.